# post DTO to the table that is type of DbEntity in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model, dto

Can anyone help me to post DTO to the table that is type of DbEntity?

in my context I have Categories table which is type of Category (DbEntity) :

```
public DbSet<Category> Categories {get;set;}
```

in my service I want to post a new category to the Categories table but I want to use my DTO instead of my DbEntity:

```
 public async Task<CategoryDTO> CreateCategory(CategoryDTO category)
 {
     await _context.Categories.AddAsync(category).Select(c => new CategoryDTO
     {
         CategoryId = c.CategoryId, 
         CategoryName = c.CategoryName
                
     }).SaveChangesAsync();
          
     return category;         
 }
```

I am getting error because Categories table is type of DbEntity and I want to add category that is type of CategoryDTO i.e data transfer object. I tried to translate my DbEntity to DTO using select but it did not work. can anyone help me to convert the types and properly add my new category to database?

this is also my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(CategoryDTO category)
        {
            if (category == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState); 
            }

            await _service.CreateCategory(category);
            return Ok(category);
        }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Actually I need to use DTO instead of DbEntity.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you're trying to insert into the database then you must create an instance of the database model class in order to do so. You must convert from the DTO to the database class. So actually I wasn't quite correct before, sorry. You should be changing `.AddAsync(category)` so you send it a DB object instead of a DTO.

Comment: yes I think I should do this for the post method.

Comment: The post method is fine. You should send the DTO there. It's only when you want to put it into the database that you need to convert it. Having DTOs and database objects as separate classes is good practice

Comment: P.S. If you don't want to write all the conversion code manually you can use something like [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) to help you more easily convert between the DTOs and database objects.

Comment: I see, thank you for the information. I am trying it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it like this:

```
public async Task <CategoryDTO> CreateCategory(CategoryDTO category)
{  
    Category myCategory = new Category()
    {    
         CategoryName = category.CategoryName
    };

    await _context.Categories.AddAsync(myCategory);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();//Save the changes
     
    //pass CategoryId back with DTO  
    category.CategoryId = myCategory.CategoryId;
            
    return category;         
}
```